# Advice on thumbnail caching for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, caching

I'm using a UITableView to display a list of images which the user has saved in the app's Documents directory. The images are large, more or less the size and resolution of the iPad's screen. I tried using this code to generate the thumbnails each time the table view is displayed, but of course it takes too long to do this, especially if there are a lot of images saved:

```
NSString *filePath = [_documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:basicFileName];

CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath], NULL);

if (!imageSource) // if no image available, we have a folder
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FolderIcon"];
}
else
{
    CFDictionaryRef options = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform,
                                                         (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent,
                                                         (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:kDefaultCellHeight], (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize,
                                                         nil];

    CGImageRef imgRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options);

    UIImage *scaledDownImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];

    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
    CFRelease(imageSource);

    cell.imageView.image = scaledDownImage;
}
```

To reduce the delay, I tried to think to think of a way to have the thumbnails already created and stored in cache the first time the user taps the button for the table view to appear. I moved the thumbnail creation to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the app delegate and have them saved to the app's Cache file. This is going to require more work to make it a reliable and efficient solution, but it occurred to me that I'm probably missing something in ImageIO that can handle this efficiently without me needing to write a lot of code. The docs on ImageIO don't seem to contain a lot of detail. Is it possible for me to create the thumbnails only once, and then embed them in the original PNG files for the images? Or is there another way to easily cache or store these thumbnails for quick access at any time?

Comment: You could store the thumbnail as a separate file. You could alternatively have the user store the photos in the photos library, which will allow you to use ALAsset's `thumbnail` property. You could also compare your implementation to the source code of [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which downloads and caches images to disk.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I'm trying to avoid is having to manage two files for every action a user takes, instead of just one. E.g. if a user deletes or changes the name of an image, I have to target code at both the original and the thumbnail. I thought there might be something in the frameworks that would take care of this in a simple way. Photo Library is not an option for this app, unfortunately. The app does give access to the Photo Library, but there also needs to be an independent store of saved images that reside within the app.